# Multiple nested HTML include directives with a nginx server

Tags: nginx, html

I have index.html:

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/Framework.inc"-->
```

Inside Framework.inc I have:

```
<!--#include file="/includes/HTML.inc"-->
```

However, when I open the page for index.html, after viewing the source code, I see the nested include did not happen and see the full include directive:

```
<!--#include file="/includes/HTML.inc"-->
```

How can we make sure nginx supports multiple levels of HTML includes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx **does** support nested SSI includes. However the SSI module processes only the `text/html` MIME type content by default, and your `.inc` files are most likely returned with something else in the `Content-Type` response HTTP header. You can adjust your global MIME types to include `.inc` extension or specify additional MIME types to process with the [`ssi_types`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi_types) directive, however I'd rather define an additional location for the `/includes/` directory content:

```
location /includes/ {
    internal;
    ssi on;
    types {
        text/html  html htm inc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ivan.  I have a follow-up question on this.  Can we do a SSI on PHP files?  The last node/include tries to include test.php, which contains <?php echo(12345); ?>.  But all we see in the source code is the content of test.php.  I did try to tweak the types:      ssi on;
    types {
        text/html html htm inc php;
    }

Comment: You are not limited to static content, SSI can be applied to any location, even those that have an HTTP `proxy_pass` or FCGI `fastcgi_pass` content handlers. However if you want to include content from those locations, you should do it is using a `virtual` subrequest, and (obviously) SSI should be turned on for those locations.

Comment: oh la la, new topics there. lol  virtual subrequest eh?..interesting monster whatever that is...

Comment: This is a static file inclusion (using a filename): `<!--#include file="HTML.inc"-->`. This is an inclusion of subrequest response (using an URI): `<!--#include virtual="/test.php"-->`. Subrequests is an internal nginx feature, widely used by a couple of modules (the most known example maybe an `auth_request_module`); the same internal nginx API is used by SSI `virtual` includes. `/test.php` here is an URI that should go through the default PHP handler location (usually something like `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`) to be interpreted via PHP-FPM.

Comment: Genius!  Wow, that worked.  The include against a PHP file inside a virtual directory does not work and pulls the content of the PHP file.  I did this, which may be overkill:          location /includes/ {
            alias "Z:/Virtual Folders/Includes/";

            ssi on;
            types {
                text/html html htm inc php;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {

            ssi on;
            types {
                text/html html htm inc php;
            }
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            }
        }